# Not sure how to write excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have 1000. What I want to do is add x% and keep adding x% to the next number

- 1000 * 0.01 = 10
- 1010 * 0.01 = 10.1
- 1020.1 * 0.01 = 10.201
- etc ...

How do I write this formula please?

Comment: http://www.excelfunctions.net/compound-interest-formula.html

Answer (score 0):

In **A2** enter:

=(1.01) * A1

and copy down

Answer (score 0):

Try the Future Value formula:

**Syntax:**

***FV(rate,nper,pmt,[pv],[type])***

Arguments:

**Rate**    *Required* The interest rate per period.

**Nper**    *Required* The total number of payment periods in an annuity.

**Pmt** *Required* The payment made each period; it cannot change over the life of the annuity. Typically, pmt contains principal and interest but no other fees or taxes. If pmt is omitted, you must include the pv argument.

**Pv**    *Optional* The present value, or the lump-sum amount that a series of future payments is worth right now. If pv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0 (zero), and you must include the pmt argument.

**Type**    *Optional* The number 0 or 1 and indicates when payments are due. If type is omitted, it is assumed to be 0.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FV-function-2eef9f44-a084-4c61-bdd8-4fe4bb1b71b3